# How do i write not greater than in a query

Tags: php, mysql

I couldn't find a real answer anywhere so I am asking.

Here is my query

```
("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE message_date < ? AND message_date //not greater than// ? AND to_user = ? OR from_user = ? ORDER BY message_date DESC")
```

I have no idea how to check that the date is not greater than the defined date

Comment: Did you try "message_date <= ?"?

Comment: not greater than nothing but "is less than"

Comment: not(message_date > new Date)

Comment: AND takes precedence over OR, so you might want to wrap the OR in parentheses.

Comment: Ok I saw a comment about redundancy, so i want to clarify, the `<` statement at the beginning of the query. For some reason it is showing things that are `>` the date that I have set.. Instead of only showing  items that are `<` the defined date it is also showing items from `>` too and I cannot figure out why, this is why I asked the question. I hope that clarifies that my questions isn't entirely moronic.

Comment: @kira423 see my comment about OR. Your query will match all rows where `from_user` equals the parameter.

Comment: @JanDvorak I just did that it didn't fix the above mentioned issue though, but I thank you greatly for pointing that out to me

Comment: @kira423 if you can't solve your issue, post your query, a test case, the expected output and the actual output (and some comment). It could qualify as a separate question.

Comment: @JanDvorak I wrapped it wrong, I only wrapped around the `from_user` instead of both `to_user` all the way to the end of `for_user` it is working great now! Thanks so much! Although since the answer didn't really follow the question because I am obviously horrible at clarifying I dunno how to go about accepting your answer. Should I ask a new one, or just let it be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two ways to write it.

One option is to simply use `<=` since "not greater than" is equivalent to "less than or equal to."

The other is to use the `NOT` modifier, e.g. `... AND NOT (message_date > ?)`.

Comment: `x<=y` is even eqivalent to `NOT(x>y)` if either argument can be null.

Answer (score 1):

'Not greater than' is the same as saying 'less than or equal to', so:

```
SELECT * FROM messages
WHERE message_date < ? AND message_date <= ? AND to_user = ? OR from_user = ?
ORDER BY message_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check if it is less, but if you want to say not, you can use not!

```
not(message_date > ?)
```

Comment: is `new Date` valid in MySQL?

Comment: new Date shoudl be replaced with the `?`

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want like this,

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages 
WHERE message_date <= ?  AND
      ? IN (to_user, from_user)
ORDER BY message_date DESC
```

*when you say not greater than, it just means less than or equal to*

Comment: You're missing the equality case.

Comment: `? IN (to_user, from_user)` may not be equivalent to `? = to_user OR ? = from_user` (although it is in a considerable amount of use-cases).